# Tooltip doesn't show up in nested user controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Label defined in UserControl1. This label is assigned with a tool tip at run-time (in .cs file).

```
mTooltip.SetToolTip(this.txtDirection2, CloseItem.ToString());
mTooltip.ShowAlways = true;
```

The UserControl1 is called within Usercontrol2 and Usercontrol3.

There also exists another usercontrol, usercontrol4.

In Usercontrol4, based on a 'if' condition Usercontrol2 and Usercontrol3 are being called.

By default Usercontrol2 is being called from Usercontrol4.In Usercontrol2, tool tip defined in UserControl1 will show when i mouse over the lablel.

But when Usercontrol3 is opened from Usercontrol4, the tooltip will never show.

I also tried debugging, by placing the debugger in UserControl1, the tooltip is getting populated with right values. It is not set to null. I also checked the tooltip value from Usercontrol4, it has the right values.

Comment: You will have to give us more code in order to help you.  Sample code that reproduces the issue for your audience.